# Having trouble binding a property in my ViewModel with a form element

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, binding, viewmodel

I have a form, below:

[image]

The filler list that you see can vary depending on what the user selects as a "Capsule Size" in the previous screen.  In otherwords, if the user chooses "Capsule 0" in the previous screen and clicks Submit, then THIS screen will show a list of fillers for that capsule.  That all works perfect.  What I need to be able to do is capture the filler chosen on this form.  When the user clicks "Create" on this form, the code then calls the "GetResults" method in the "Process" controller:

```
public ActionResult GetResults(ProcessViewModel vm)
{
    List<Results> results = context.GetResults();
    return View(results);
}
```

And here's what my ViewModel that this particular View is operating on:

```
public class ProcessViewModel
{
    public audit_session AuditSession { get; set; }

    public int NumberOfCapsules { get; set; }

    public int CapsuleFK { get; set; }

    public audit_ingredient_active Active1 { get; set; }
    public audit_ingredient_active Active2 { get; set; }
    public audit_ingredient_active Active3 { get; set; }
    public audit_ingredient_active Active4 { get; set; }
    public audit_ingredient_active Active5 { get; set; }
    public audit_ingredient_active KeyActive { get; set; }

    public audit_ingredient_filler Filler { get; set; }

    public bool E4M { get; set; }
    public bool K100M { get; set; }

    public List<filler> Fillers { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to be able to do is capture the filler chosen and bind that in somehow to Filler in my ViewModel.  How can I do this?  Everything else is binding correctly (E4M, K100M, and every other field on the form that you can't see).

Here's what the markup looks like for my filler list- **I suspect there's a problem in here because I'm not 100% confident in this markup**:

```
    <label>Choose Filler:</label><br />
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        @foreach (var i in Model.Fillers)
        {
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Filler, "false", new { name = "radio-choice", id = i.pk });
            <label for="@i.pk">@i.name</label>
        }
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: why are you customizing the id and name of the radio button?

Comment: The name is because it needs to be named "radio-choice" in order for jQuery Mobile to render it as the UI button you see on the form...

Comment: What version of MVC are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are overriding your radio button name, maybe you could try binding the `Filler` property manually, instead of relying on the default model binder.

You may need to add an extra `string radio_choice` parameter in your controller signature (or capture it directly using `Request.Form["radio-choice"]`), and assigning them to the `Filler` property of the `vm`.